# Snap.svg doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

This might be a simple and silly question.

I download this library [here](http://snapsvg.io/), and then I want to quickly get start it.

So, This is **test.html** in download package.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="dist/snap.svg.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var s = Snap();
            Snap.load("inkscape.svg", function (f) {
                console.log(f.select('path[sodipodi:nodetypes="cc"]'));
            });

            var c = Snap("#svg");
            // Lets create big circle in the middle:
            var bigCircle = c.circle(150, 150, 100);
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the browser seems blank, and console threw some errors

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/inkscape.svg 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'circle' of null
```

Did I miss some file?

Um, I am a beginner, should I download `inkscape.svg` by myself and reload it?

Comment: Is `inkscape.svg` a file in your root (same as `test.html`) directory?

Comment: Yes you should download inkscape.svg, put it where your test.html is, and reload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 3 problems here...

1) It can't find the inkscape.svg file. Its not clear if this is runnng just locally on your PC, or on a remote server though, but you need to sort that, either place it alongside this html file, on the server or locally, however you are accessing it.

2) Snap.load will load a file into a fragment, but doesn't append it to the DOM. You need to do something to append the fragment.

Eg s.append(f) to add the lot.

3) The line c = Snap("#svg") needs to be INSIDE (or at least called from inside) the Snap.load function. This is assuming #svg is in the loaded file. Otherwise Snap goes off to load the svg, carries on running, tries to do Snap("#svg") but the file hasn't finished loading yet. So the logic needs to change a bit.

Eg

```
Snap.load( 'inkscake.svg', fragment ) {
    s.append(fragment);
    doOtherStuffOnceLoadingComplete();
}

function doOtherStuffOnceLoadingComplete() {
     var c = Snap("#svg");
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the SVG docs getting started guide it says:

```
// First lets create our drawing surface out of existing SVG element
// If you want to create new surface just provide dimensions
// like s = Snap(800, 600);
var s = Snap("#svg");
```

http://snapsvg.io/start/

I didn't catch the part that says "Existing SVG" and just looked at the `#svg` code and assumed that you could target any element with ID #svg, but really the tag HAS to be `<svg>`, not `<div>` or anything else, or the `Snap()` constructor will not initialize and `.circle()` (or any draw method) will come back with an error that it's not a function.

So, always use

```
<svg id="someID"></svg>
```

and

```
var s = Snap('#someID');
```